# ComboBox is not working in an EditorGridPanel for ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework

I am new to ExtJS and need to put a `ComboBox` in an `EditorGridPanel`.

My code so far does not create the combobox in the `EditorGridPanel` and the `EditorGridPanel` does not display as well.

Here is the code and thanks for your help. capturetheflag

```
   /*==== INVOICE DATA START =======================================================*/

/* create the ComboBox editor */
var idCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: 'id',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField:'id',
    store: '',  //what do I store here?? 
    triggerAction: 'all'
});

var idRenderer = function(value,metaData,record){
   // try record.data.teacher here
   return "displayValue"


var iLineItemCM = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([

    {
        id: 'i_line_item_id',
        header: 'Line Item ID',
        dataIndex: 'i_line_item_id',
        width: 80,
        editor: this.idCombo(),
        renderer:idRenderer

    }

,{
        id:'i_line_item_name',
        header: "Line Item Name",
        dataIndex: 'i_line_item_name',
        width: 315,
        resizable: true,
        align: 'center',
        editor: new Ext.form.TextArea({
            allowBlank: false
        })
    }
    ,{
        header: "Amount",
        dataIndex: 'i_line_item_amt',
        width: 80,
        align: 'right',
        renderer: 'usMoney',
        editor: new Ext.form.NumberField({
            allowBlank: false,
            allowNegative: false,
            maxValue: 100000
        })
    }
    ]);

var iLineItemRec =
new Ext.data.Record.create([
    {
    name: 'i_line_item_id'    ,
    mapping: 'i_line_item_id'  ,
    type: 'string'
}
,{
    name: 'i_line_item_name'    ,
    mapping: 'i_line_item_name'  ,
    type: 'string'
}
,{
    name: 'i_line_item_amt'     ,
    mapping: 'i_line_item_amt'   ,
    type: 'string'
}
]);

var iLineItemStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: '',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'rows'
    },
    iLineItemRec
    )
});

var iLineItemGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    id: 'iLineItemStore',
    store: iLineItemStore,
    cm: iLineItemCM,
    cls: 'iLineItemGrid',
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    frame: true,
    //title:'Edit Plants?',
    //plugins:checkColumn,
    clicksToEdit:1,
    viewConfig: {
        //forceFit: true
        autoFit:true
    },
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Add',
        tooltip:'Add the line item',
        handler : function(){
            var r = new iLineItemRec({
                i_line_item_name: '',
                i_line_item_amt: ''
            });
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            iLineItemStore.insert(0, r);
            iLineItemGrid.startEditing(0, 0);
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Delete',
        tooltip:'Remove the selected line item',
        handler: function(){
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            var r = iLineItemGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCell();
            iLineItemStore.removeAt(r[1]);
        }

    }

    ]
});
/////////////////// CODE ENDS
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at sencha examples: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example Find a close fitting example to your use case and start by copying their code. Get that to work on your machine first. Then incrementally modify it to get it closer to what you need. If you run into trouble ask specific questions here.

Comment: the combobox will need to be populated from a data store

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a data store and bind that to your combobox. Then in the combo config, you can tell it which field from the store you want to display and which field you want for the value. Here is an example from ExtJS 4 API Docs:

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],  // fields that your data consists of
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,  // here you use the store
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',  // you tell your combobox which field to display from the store
    valueField: 'abbr',  // you tell your combobox which field to use for value from the store
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

If you use combo.getValue(), and if e.g. "Alaska" were selected in your combobox, it would return "AK". You can also use the same field as displayField and valueField if you like.